# Openssl aes load key from file

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, cryptography, aes

Using openssl with aes256 by passing password works fine:

```
openssl enc -iv BABA -aes256 -in message.txt -out message.enc -base64  -k 1234
openssl enc -d -iv BABA -aes256 -in message.enc -out message.txt -base64  -k 1234
```

What I am trying to do is to generate an aes256 key and save it in a file. Then use the key file for encryption/decryption actions.
I found this procedure:

```
openssl rand -base64 256 > symm_key
openssl enc -aes256 -e -in message.txt -out cipher.bin -pass file:symm_key -salt
openssl enc -aes256 -d -in cipher.bin -out message.txt -pass file:symm_key -salt
```

Any other solution? I do not want to use password.

Comment: With `-K` and `-iv` key and IV can be specified *directly* (which e.g. have to be loaded from a file beforehand). The values must be passed as hex encoded strings. See [openssl enc, sec. options, -K and -iv](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/enc.html) for more details. Note that `openssl rand` requires the length in *bytes*, so for AES-256 it would make sense to use: `openssl rand -hex 32`.

Comment: `openssl aes256 -in message.txt -out notes.txt.enc -K \`cat aeskey\` -iv \`cat iv\``, where `aeskey` and `iv` contain the key and iv produced as described in the previous comment by @Topaco.